# Matrix example invertible

Tags: matrices

> $$A = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & -1  \\ 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix} $$ Find the $2 \times 2$ matrix $X$ such that $XA^2 − XA^{-1} = A$.

Can anyone advise me on how to do questions like this? Very confusing. Trying to teach myself matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint

Multiply by $A$ to the right, to get

$$XA^3 - X = A^2$$

$$X(A^3 - \mathbb{1}) = A^2$$

Then you just need to compute $A^3 - \mathbb{1} = AAA - \mathbb{1}$ and $A^2 = AA$.

At the end, calling $A^3 - \mathbb{1} = B$ you will have

$$XB = A^2$$

Multiply for $B^{-1}$ to the right to get the solution:

$$X = A^2 B^{-1}$$

**Remark**

Notice that you have to do with simple $2x2$ matrices, hence their inverse is a piece of cake. In general you have:

$$
M = 
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d 
\end{pmatrix}
~~~~~~~~~~~ M^{-1} = \frac{1}{\text{det} M}
\begin{pmatrix}
d & -b \\
-c & a
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Of course you need to have $\text{det} M \neq 0$ in order to have an invertible matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: use Cayley-Hamilton to find out an equation $A^2+aA+bI=0$.
Then you can reduce all higher matrix powers $A^k$ for $k\ge 2$, so that
$A$ appears only in degree $1$ and $0$. Then $X=A^2(A^3-I)^{-1}$ can be reduced, too.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively:
$$XA^2 − XA^{-1} = A \Rightarrow X(A^2-A^{-1})=A \Rightarrow X=A\cdot (A^2-A^{-1})^{-1}.$$
Note:
$$A^2=\begin{pmatrix} 2 & -1  \\ 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix}^2=\begin{pmatrix} 3 & -1 \\ 2 & \ \ 0 \end{pmatrix}; $$
$$A^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix} 2 & -1  \\ 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix}^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ -1 & -2 \end{pmatrix};$$
$$(A^2-A^{-1})^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix} 2 & -2  \\ 3 & -2 \end{pmatrix}^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 1 \\ -\frac32 & 1 \end{pmatrix};$$
Hence:
$$X=\begin{pmatrix} 2 & -1  \\ 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 1 \\ -\frac32 & 1 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} -\frac12 & 1 \\ \ \ \frac12 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$